# Can't get related set

Tags: django, django-models

Why can't I use `page.item_set` to get the related items for the page model?
I obtain the following error:

> ```
> 'Page' object has no attribute 'item_set'
> ```

My code:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("Page", blank=True, null=True, related_name="parent_page")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Item(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name="item")
    key = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="builder/item", null=True, blank=True)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)
    goto = models.ForeignKey(Page, null=True, blank=True, related_name="goto_page")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've named the relation `item` instead. Try `page.item.all()` instead.

The `related_name` defaults to the lowercase version of the classname with `_set` appended to it. As you've noticed however, you can override it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `related_name` for Item is "item", not "item_set", so you would call `Page.item`. To get all items, you would call `Page.item.all()` this way. If you omit the `related_name` attribute on the `Item.page` field though, the name will default to `item_set`.